# any with if using one for loop

Tags: python

I am doing a check , if any element fulfills the conditions

```
if any( plus > minimum and minus > minimum for el in alist):

    # do something
```

but with having (adding) in the same loop:

```
if numpy.isnan(el.error):
    plus = el.value
    minus = el.value
else:
    plus = el.value + el.error
    minus = el.value - el.error
```

So, I want to have inside `any()` function , a for loop and an if else statement.

Comment: Why not to do the if statement before the `any() ` function?

Comment: @GijsDenHollander:Because I have to use another for loop.I was wondering if it is possible without it.

Comment: But in the `any(..)` you do not do anything with the `el`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem:That's why I have to insert the if statement in the any..

Comment: You can use ternary operators for that...

Comment: I think something like this should work.  `any( plus>minimum and minus>minimum for plus, minus in ((el.value, el.value) if numpy.isnan(el.error) else (el.value+el.error, el.value - el.error) for el in alist))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the logic correctly, you want to make sure `el.value` +/- `el.error` is greater than `minimum`, as long as the `error` exists (else just use the `value`).

You don't actually have to check both sides, since you can just `abs` your `error` before subtracting. You can define a helper function:

```
def min_val(el):
    if numpy.isnan(el.error):
        return el.value
    return el.value - numpy.abs(el.error)
```

Then use that in your `any` call:

```
if any(min_val(el) > minimum for el in alist):
```

You could also write the helper as a lambda, or even stick the whole expression inside the `any` call, but it gets harder to read:

```
min_val = lambda el: el.value - (0 if numpy.isnan(el.error) else abs(el.error))
```

Answer (score 1):

make a function and use that in your `any` call:

```
def checker(el, minimum):
    plus = minus = 0 # make sure to initialize
    if numpy.isnan(el.error):
        plus = el.value
        minus = el.value
    else:
        plus = el.value + el.error
        minus = el.value - el.error
    return plus > minimum and minus > minimum
```

then make use of `any`:

```
if any(checker(el,minimum) for el in alist):
    # do something!!
```

you could also do a disgusting one liner (alike to the comment by Patrick).